# Neo4J Search for "graph pattern"

Tags: neo4j

I try to find some identical pattern in a graph (sorry, don't know if "pattern" the right word ...).

Here's an exemple :

I have a graph like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVejP.png)
But sometimes, i have a specific pattern like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwQT2.png)
"Node 1" and "Node 2" have the same "father".

Is there a way to find this kind of thing in the entire graph ?

I try something link this but it doesn't work :

```
match (n:node)<-[:rel]-(m:node)<-[:rel]-(p:node) where n = p return n,m,p;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Easy peezy!

```
MATCH (n:node)<-[:rel]-(m:node)<-[:rel]-(p:node), (n)<-[:rel]-(p)
RETURN n,m,p;
```